# Approximating Probabilities of Winning a Game with a 9% Winning Chance

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A game has a winning probability of $9\%$. If you play $10$ times, what is the probability that you win $$(i)\text{ exactly once}$$ $$(ii) \text{at least once}$$ $$(iii) \text{less than 3 times or more than 5 times}$$

Since this is a binomial distribution $\frac{winning}{losing}$, I approached (i) the following way:

$$\frac{10!}{9!} \times {0.09}^1 \times {0.91}^9 = 38.5\%$$

Is this correct? Because it seems rather high to me that one has almost a $40%$ probability of winning EXACTLY once. But my intuition might be (as is usually is) flawed.

For the second subtask now I assume that one could simply calculate

$$1 - {0.91}^{10} = 61.1\%$$

Here I wanted to ask, I one were not to use this shortcut, but to actually add all binomial probabilities, if it would be admissible to approximate the result normally in the following way:

$$E(x) = np = 100.09 = 0.9~~ \text{and}~~ \sigma = \sqrt {({100.09}\times{0.91})} = 0.905$$

If we include all results from $1$ to $10$ wins, with continuity correction $(1-0.5 = 0.5)$ and standardisation we have

$$1 - P(X ≥ 1) = P\left(Z ≥ \frac{(0.5-0.9)}{0.905}\right) = P(Z ≥ -0.442) = 67.1\%$$

However, this approximation seems quite off form the actual solution of $61.1\%$, where did I do a mistake? Or can't you use a normal approximation for the task in question?

For the last subtask I again started by calculating the binomial probability:

$$1 - \text{P(three wins) - P(four wins) - P(five wins)} \\=1 - \left(\frac{10!}{3!7!} \times {0.09}^3 \times {0.91}^7 \right) - \left(\frac{10!}{4!6!} \times {0.09}^4 \times {0.91}^6) \right) - \left(\frac{10!}{5!5!} \times {0.09}^5 \times {0.91}^5 \right)= 94.6 \%$$ Would there be a faster way to calculate this?

Again, if you would approximate normally:

$$1 - P\left(\frac{(2.5-0.9)}{0.905} ≤ Z ≤ \frac{(5.5-0.9)}{0.905}\right) = 1 - P(1.768 ≤ Z ≤ 5.083) = 96.2\%$$

I seem to be doing something wrong with the normal approximation, but I can't figure out what is is. Can someone spot the mistake?

Comment: Side note: I would get my hand slapped by probability theory lector every time I said probability was in percents.

Comment: Approximation to normal distribution is reliable for large $n$. That said, $n=10$ is not that large.

Comment: Could also approximate with Poisson, but the problem is again that $n$ is too small. It becomes reliable for small $p$ ($0,09$ is small enough) and $n>60$ or so.

Comment: If the number of games times the probability of winning any one game is close to $1$, then the probability of winning exactly one game is close to $1/e$.  It's higher than you might think, especially if the number of games is large (say, a million, or something like that).

Comment: One problem with the normal approximation of (iii) is using 1.5 instead of 2.5, but there's more to it than that. See my Answ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for showing your progress working these problems.

Throughout you have $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=10,p=0.09).$
The corresponding PDF is
$$P(X = k) ={10\choose k}(.09)^k(.91)^{10-k},$$
for $k = 0,1,\dots,10.$

(i) I used R to do the arithmetic to get $P(X=1) = = 0.3851,$ in agreement with your answer. [In R, `dbinom` is a binomial PDF and `pbinom` a binomial CDF.]

```
dbinom(1, 10, .09)
[1] 0.3851368
```

(ii) $P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X = 0) = 0.6106,$ as you say.

```
1 - dbinom(0, 10, .09)
[1] 0.6105839
```

> However, it is not a good idea to use a normal approximation here. A common rule of thumb is to use
> normal approximations only if $np$ and $n(1-p)$ both
> exceed 5 (or some other number depending on the author's
> degree of fussiness). This condition is not satisfied here. Using 5 in the rule, you can often expect two
> places of accuracy--if $p \approx 1/2$ and less accuracy
> for $p$ near $0$ or $1.$ [In this particular computation $P(X=0)$ is *very poorly* approximated by the relevant normal distribution.]

(iii) As you say, you want
$$P(X < 3) + P(X > 5) = 1 - P(3 \le X \le 5) \\=
P(X\le 5) - P(X\le 2) = 0.0540$$ (to four places). Computing with the PDF formula
it may be easiest to add the terms for the three
values you don't want, and then subtract to get
$1 - 0.0540 = 0.9460.$

```
pbinom(5, 10, .09) - pbinom(2, 10, .09)
[1] 0.05395899
diff(pbinom(c(2,5), 10, .09))
[1] 0.05395899
sum(dbinom(3:5, 10, .09))
[1] 0.05395899
```

If I wanted to try a normal approximation for this part, here is how I would approach it. First $\mu = E(X) = np = 0.9$ and $\sigma =  SD(X) = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = 0.9050.$

Now we approximate
$1 - P(3 \le X \le 5) = 1 - P(2.5 < X < 5.5),$ using continuity correction.

$$P(2.5 < X < 5.5) = \left(\frac{2.5-0.9}{0.9050}
< \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{5.5-0.9}{0.9050}\right)\\
\approx P(1.77 < Z < 5.08) = 0.0384,$$
where $Z$ is standard normal and the final probability
is from printed tables. Then the desired probability
is approximately $1-0.0384= 0.9616.$

There can be two important sources of error when
you make a normal approximation in this way:
(a) The normal approximation may not be very
good and (b) Rounding error.

- As for (a), we
  already know the usual rule for using a normal
  approximation doesn't hold.
- And for (b), I have
  rounded $\sigma.$ Also, because margins of most printed normal tables only have two places, I have rounded look-up values 1.77 and 5.08 to two places.
- Finally (least important), the body of the table has only
  four places (and after subtraction we may have
  only three places of accuracy).

By avoiding standardization and using $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu,\sigma)$ directly in R, I can
avoid rounding error. [In this particular problem,
rounding errors nearly cancel one another and so are
not important.]

```
1 - diff(pnorm(c(2.5,5.5), mu, sg))
[1] 0.9614683
```

A plot of the exact binomial PDF probabilities along with a density function of the approximating
distribution shows the major source of error.
The fit is very bad--especially near $0.$

[image]

```
k=0:10; PDF = dbinom(k, 10, .09)
hdr = "Poor Approx. of BINOM(10,.9), by NORM(.9,.905)"
plot(k, PDF, type="h", ylim=c(0,.5), lwd=3, col="blue", main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 curve(dnorm(x, mu, sg), -.5, 10.5, add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
 abline(v=c(2.5,5.5), lty="dotted")
```

Comment: You have a typo in the second line, with $20$ instead of $10$.  Well done

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it. And others :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Comparison of Binomial and Poisson Distributions**

Exactly one time:
$$
\binom{10}{1}.09^1.91^9=0.38513682
$$
Poisson approximation: (off by $5.0\%$)
$$
e^{-.9}\frac{.9^1}{1!}=0.36591269
$$
At least once:
$$
1-\binom{10}{0}.09^0.91^{10}=0.61058388
$$
Poisson approximation: (off by $2.8\%$)
$$
1-e^{-.9}\frac{.9^0}{0!}=0.59343034
$$
Less than three or more than five:
$$
1-\sum_{k=3}^5\binom{10}{k}.09^k.91^{10-k}=0.94604101
$$
Poisson Approximation: (off by $0.9\%$)
$$
1-\sum_{k=3}^5e^{-.9}\frac{.9^k}{k!}=0.93748656
$$
[image]